# i tried to delete grails 3.0.3 from my mac but cannot get rid of the gvm folders

Tags: grails, uninstallation

i'm on a mac osx 10.10 and tried uninstall, which didn't work so I tried to rm the .gvm

all the files where removed but i can't get rid of these 
bin
etc
ext
src
tmp
...

i would greatly appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm -rf ~/.gvm` should delete the folder and everything in it.